# How to run a background function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, apns-php

I am using codeigniter with REST API for web service.

I want to send multiple apple push notification in an certain action. The problem is its taking time to response because its sending all the notification and response the web service call.

I need web service call should response immediately and then it will send notification in background.

Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

Assign a common function in common.js ,then trigger a function for every 2 min and run it in background as ajax function

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 5000); // for every 5 sec
```

Comment: How can i trigger every 2 min ? Can you please explain brief ?